# How to write a search query for this form

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to write a search query that search on the criteria like city, rent, area. i am new to database and sql queries. How to write query. Please help. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. My form snapshot is here ->>

[image: Form Snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Selecting records from MySQL table is basic task. I recommend you to read [W3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp) on SQL.

What you want here is done with one simple SELECT query:

```
//Connecting to MySQL and selecting DB
mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');

//Actual SELECT query
$qh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE city='".$_POST['city']."' AND rent='".$_POST['rent']."' AND area='".$_POST['area']."'");

//Getting query results by rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qh))
{
   //Do something with $row here
}
```

**EDIT:**
I used `$_POST` variable just for simplicity. Note that you should always check/validate it's content before using it in a query this way. (To prevent [SQL injection](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Comment: Calling `mysql_real_escape_string` in the example is not that hard and it might help people who just blindly copy the code. (Yes, copying code without understanding it is a terrible idea, but why not show good examples.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `WHERE` clause. You can have multiple [conditions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) joined by [boolean operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html) such as `AND` or `OR`. For example:

```
SELECT ... WHERE
    type = 123
    AND rent BETWEEN 100 AND 200
    AND city = 567
    AND area LIKE '%Name of an area%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM ads
WHERE type = 'Living House'
AND rent > 50 AND rent < 300
AND city = 'London'
AND area LIKE '%westminster%'
```

You can take a look at [W3School's SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp) for more informations about SQL basics.